# nestjs graphql - keep data and use it for other request

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I am using nestjs graphql and integrating to other system and for this, I have to consume one API to get the jwt token and this token is valid for 1 hr.

after this, i have to use this token for all graphql requests for the next 1 hr.

can anyone help me to provide me the best approach, where should I keep this jwt token so that I can reuse this for all further requests come to graphql

I heard about Redis but not sure whether it is good for this scenario or not

Answer (score 0):

I found Keyv is fulfilling my need and happy to achieve my goal with this.